# Filter URL with regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, filter, preg-match

Is someone willing to help me filtering a URL using regex? I've come pretty far, but I stumble upon one last issue.

**Scenario:**

1. The user submits the link of their SoundCloud song in a Gravity Forms website field.
2. The script automatically ads https:// automatically if the user does not add it.
3. Removes **www.** and **m.** from the URL.
4. Sometimes a link with a private URL extension is submitted: https://soundcloud.com/username/songtitle/s-qciX1vDI2Cq

What can I do so the script also removes **s-qciX1vDI2Cq** from the URL too?

**Example input**
http://www.soundcloud.com/username/songtitle/s-qciX1vDI2Cq

**Example output**
https://soundcloud.com/username/songtitle

Many thanks in advance!

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render', 'itsg_check_website_field_value' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation', 'itsg_check_website_field_value' );
function itsg_check_website_field_value( $form ) {
    foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {  // for all form fields
        if ( 'website' == $field['type'] || ( isset( $field['inputType'] ) && 'website' == $field['inputType']) ) {  // select the fields that are 'website' type
            $value = RGFormsModel::get_field_value($field);  // get the value of the field

            if (! empty($value) ) { // if value not empty
                $field_id = $field['id'];  // get the field id

                if (! preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $value) ) {  // if value does not start with ftp:// http:// or https://
                    $value = "https://" . $value;  // add https:// to start of value
                }

                if ( preg_match("/(https?:\/\/)(www\.|m\.)?soundcloud\.com\/([^\s\n]+)\/([^\s\n]+)\/([^\s\n]+)", $value)) {
                    $temp = explode("/", $value);
                    array_pop($temp);
                    $value = implode("/", $temp);
                }


                preg_match("/(https?:\/\/)(www\.|m\.)?([^\s\n]+)(\/+)?/", $value, $extractedDomain);
                $value = "https://" . $extractedDomain[3];

                preg_match('/^(.*?)(\?.*)?$/', $value, $noSearch);
                $value = trim($noSearch[1], '/') . '';

                $_POST['input_' . $field_id] = $value; // update post with new value
            }
        }
    }
    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **regex** pattern

```
^(?:https?:\/\/|)(?:www|m)\.(soundcloud\.com\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+)(?:\/.*?|)$
```

and do a replacement with

```
http://$1
```

Test it and see explanation (on right top corner) at https://regex101.com/r/mwa4JP/1

---

See **PHP** demo at https://www.ideone.com/rdKb3P

```
preg_replace("/^(?:https?:\/\/|)(?:www|m)\.(soundcloud\.com\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+)(?:\/.*?|)$/",
             "http://$1", $input);
```

To accept uppercase letters in optional `www.` and `m.` prefixes and/or in the `soundcloud.com` domain name, add `i` regex modifier:

```
/^(?:https?:\/\/|)(?:www|m)\.(soundcloud\.com\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+)(?:\/.*?|)$/i
```

Answer (score -1):

I would go for the regex  '///'

```
$url = 'http://www.soundcloud.com/username/songtitle/s-qciX1vDI2Cq';
$regex = '/\//';
$a = preg_split($regex, $url);
print_r($a);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http:
    [1] =>
    [2] => www.soundcloud.com
    [3] => username
    [4] => songtitle
    [5] => s-qciX1vDI2Cq
)
```

Now you can join these elements from 0 to 4 to give the correct url.